# load percona database dump to mysql

Tags: mysql, percona

percona version:  5.7.16-10-log - Percona Server (GPL)
mysql version: 5.7.17

When loading percona dump to simple mysql, phpmyadmin stops responding. Load fails. Is there any features in DB transfer.

Comment: Sorry this is a long time ago, but what did you mean by a percona dump? 
The other thing I have found in the past (not Percona) is that zipping up the file helps as there are file size limits on most host sites. This might not apply in your case, but it is just a thought.

Comment: I was helped by the hosting company to load the dump. I think the problem was in download mode in FileZilla. I was using ASCII mode instead of binary.